# how can i shorten the border-left height property in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have made a simple address panel where i have made three panels of each consisting of address,phone number and email.Each panels consist of an icon and an paragraph besides it.I have use vertical align:top and display table property to align them side by side.Then i have given a border-left property to the main div that consist all this divs inside of it.I want to have a design such that the line should go through the icons and and not exceed the top and bottom icon.But the problem is happening here where the main consist all these icons and there are some padding and margin, hence it is crossing over and can't fix it even when i remove margin and padding.I want to have a design such that the icons shouldn't exceed top and bottom icons.And if anyone is suggesting position property,just keep in mind i have a div inside another col-md-6 which has a position absolute.

Here is the HTML part:-

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <h2 class="heading-title">Drop in our office</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <div class="address-top">
                        <div class="address-repeat">
                            <div class="address-left">
                                <div class="body-widget">
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="address-right">
                                <div class="body-widget">
                                    <label>ADDRESS</label>
                                    <p>Huatai Securities (USA)10 Hudson Yards 41FlNY, NY 10001</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="address-repeat">
                            <div class="address-left">
                                <div class="body-widget">
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="address-right">
                                <div class="body-widget">
                                    <label>LETS TALK</label>
                                    <p>212-763-8166</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="address-repeat">
                            <div class="address-left">
                                <div class="body-widget">
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="address-right">
                                <div class="body-widget">
                                    <label>GENERAL SUPPORT</label>
                                    <p>boardoffice@htsc.com</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS part:-

```
.address-left, .address-right{
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.address-left{
    width:50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.address-right{
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
.address-repeat{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 -12px;
}

.address-top{
    width: 100%;
    border-left:2px solid #d5d5d5;
    margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
}

#contact-us .address-right p{
    color:#5e5e5e;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-size:14px;
    width:200px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
#contact-us label{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-HvCn';
    font-size:17px;
    color:#343434;
}
#contact-us i{
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    line-height:23px;
    padding:1px 0 0 6px;
    background-color:#e70020;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `::before` pseudo element instead of left-border like this:

```css
.address-left, .address-right{
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.address-left{
    width:50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.address-right{
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}
.address-repeat{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 -12px;
}

.address-top{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 10px;
    position:relative;
}

.address-top::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25px;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 2px;
  content: '';
  background-color: #d5d5d5;
  z-index: -1;
}

#contact-us .address-right p{
    color:#5e5e5e;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-size:14px;
    width:200px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
#contact-us label{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTStd-HvCn';
    font-size:17px;
    color:#343434;
}
#contact-us i{
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    line-height:23px;
    padding:1px 0 0 6px;
    background-color:#e70020;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <h2 class="heading-title">Drop in our office</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <div class="address-top">
      <div class="address-repeat">
        <div class="address-left">
          <div class="body-widget">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="address-right">
          <div class="body-widget">
            <label>ADDRESS</label>
            <p>Huatai Securities (USA)10 Hudson Yards 41FlNY, NY 10001</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="address-repeat">
        <div class="address-left">
          <div class="body-widget">
            <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="address-right">
          <div class="body-widget">
            <label>LETS TALK</label>
            <p>212-763-8166</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="address-repeat">
        <div class="address-left">
          <div class="body-widget">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="address-right">
          <div class="body-widget">
            <label>GENERAL SUPPORT</label>
            <p>boardoffice@htsc.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it is coming on top of the icons which is not needed it should be behind the icons.

Comment: Well, you asked how to shorten the border ;-) I thought I will let you figure the rest of it out yourself. But let me see..

Comment: ya i tried, i used the z-index property and gave the address top z-index:0 and gave the i element z-index:1. Still not taking those value.Please if you could help

Comment: I have updated the code example in a similar way, you can check!

Comment: wow,that was really nice,i used the z-index property like the above but it didn't worked.I still have to brush up my skills.Thank you so much for your help. Could you please advice me on how should i improve and master my HTML and Css like a advanced level?

Comment: I am still learning too, but this series of articles provided a very good base for me: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/

Comment: Okay,thanks man. Will definitely study that article. This was great.